# NSData returning nil after upgrading the phone to iOS10

Tags: objective-c, ios10

Below is our code block used in our app to connect to web service. Our app used to work fine in iOS 9, but users running on iOS 10 now experience and issue where the app fails to connect to the web service:

The data on line 8 returns `nil`. The error returns `domain:@"NSCocoaErrorDomain" -code:256`

The url we used in this format is: "https://xxx.xxx.com/xxiOSService/partFinder.svc/GetLogin/ID=2451789487"

Any idea why it only fails in iOS 10?

```
1) NSString *_login = badgeTxt.text;
2) NSString *lab = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _login];
3) NSString *filepath = [WcfServiceURL1 absoluteString];
4) NSString *test = [URL stringByAppendingString:filePath];
5) NSString *GetURL1 = [test stringByAppendingString:lab];
6) NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:GetURL1];
7) NSError *error = nil;
8) NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&
9)          error];
10) if (!error)
11) {
12)     NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
13)                                     JSONObjectWithData:data
14)                                       options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers    
15)                                     error:&error];
```

Comment: Is `url` valid and not nil?

Comment: Can you replicate this in the debugger? What's the value of `url`? FYI - there is a lot of bad code in there. Calling `absoluteString` on a file URL is probably wrong on line 3. If it's really a file path, you want `path`, not `absoluteString`. Using `stringWithFormat:` is pointless on line 2.

Comment: Please share your info.plist value for AppTransportSecuritySettings.  It must permit connection with xxx.xxx.com.

Comment: @Larme  yes url is valid. as i mentioned earlier it works in ios9 and not in ios10.

Comment: @danh below is the plist

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>items</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>assets</key>
   <array>
    <dict>
     <key>kind</key>
     <string>software-package</string>
     <key>url</key>
     <string>https://XXX.YYY.com/IphoneIPA/ZZZ.ipa</string>
    </dict>

Comment: </array>
   <key>metadata</key>
   <dict>
    <key>bundle-identifier</key>
    <string>companyName.applicationName</string>
    <key>bundle-version</key>
    <string>1.3</string>
    <key>kind</key>
     <string>software</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>applicationName</string>
   </dict>
  </dict>
 </array>
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: @rmaddy below is the url we are using. it is trying to pass the parameter ID = 245178948 to a function called GetLogin in the web service. 
"https://xxx.yyy.com/xxiOSService/partFinder.svc/GetLogin/ID=2451789487"

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter that the app seemed to work earlier. This line was *always* dead wrong:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url
    options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
```

Never use `dataWithContentsOfURL` to do networking. If you want to download something, *download* it (with NSURLSession).

Comment: we tried the code block below but no luck.
1) NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:GetUrl];
2) NSError *error = nil;
3) NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&
error];
4) NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
5) NSURLResponse * response = nil;
6) NSError * error1 = nil;
7) NSData * data1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
returningResponse:&response
error:&error1];

Comment: (1) I said NSURLSession, not NSURLConnection. (2) You are still doing it wrong: you are still networking _synchronously_. Stop it. Just stop it.

Comment: we tried both code blocks below and we still get error 256. please help.

Comment: NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                         completionHandler:
     ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        
     }];

Comment: NSString *dataUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxx.xxx.com/xxiOSService/partFinder.svc/GetLogin/ID=2451789487"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dataUrl];
NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

Comment: }];
sorry i missed the brackets in the comment above.